# Read xml data in php

Tags: php, xml

I have a xml file output.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
  <item>
    <key type="your_id">CYBEX-525A/DA-IPOD</key>
    <key type="web">cybex-525at-arc-trainer</key>
    <key type="web">standard-console-2573</key>
    <key type="name">Cybex 525AT Arc Trainer</key>
    <key type="name">Standard console</key>
    <review>
      <order_id>1544346 1</order_id>
      <author_nick>Brock</author_nick>
      <author_email>bb@GMAIL.COM</author_email>
      <date type="accepted">2013-10-14</date>
      <comment type="overall">This cardio machine is exceptional. It works every part of your leg muscles if you rotate through the height settings and include calf-raises and squats during your routine. It also works your shoulders and biceps if you focus on working them while operating the arm poles. Unlike a standard elliptical it will raise your heart rate and cause you to sweat heavily soon after you start your routine. If you're a runner and are used to using a treadmill, you will feel satisfied after using this machine. It is kind of addictive because your body feels so good during and after use. I have combined 30 minutes on the treadmill with 30 minutes on the Arc for weight-loss, muscle tone, and cardiovascular training.</comment>
      <score type="overall">5</score>
    </review>
    </item>
</items>
```

I need to save it in db, I'm just using below code to save data

```
if(file_exists('output.xml')){
    $languages = simplexml_load_file("output.xml");
    //echo '<pre>'; print_r($languages) ; die;
    foreach($languages as $item){
             echo '<pre>'; print_r($item->key) ; die;   
            foreach($item->review as $review){
                 $order_id    = $review[0]->order_id;
                 $authorName  = $review[0]->author_nick;
                 $authorEmail = strtolower($review[0]->author_email);
                 $comment     = $review[0]->comment;
                 $score       = $review[0]->score;
                 $date        = $review[0]->date;

        }
    }
}
```

I need to get value of `<key type="your_id">CYBEX-525A/DA-IPOD</key>` and   `<key type="web">cybex-525at-arc-trainer</key>` but unable to get data 
when i print `echo '<pre>'; print_r($item->key) ; die;` within loop I'm getting following out put:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [type] => your_id
        )

    [0] => CYBEX-525A/DA-IPOD
    [1] => cybex-525at-arc-trainer
    [2] => standard-console-2573
    [3] => Cybex 525AT Arc Trainer
    [4] => Standard console
)
```

Is there any method for get all these data.

Comment: Why are you calling `die` before reaching your second loop? 
[die doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php)

Comment: Because I need  <key type="your_id">CYBEX-525A/DA-IPOD</key> data before second loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DOMXpath::evaluate()` allows you to use expression to fetch nodes and scalar values from an XML DOM. The expression defines if the result is a node list or a scalar value. You can iterate a node list with `foreach()`.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xmlString);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($document);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/items/item') as $item) {
  var_dump(
    [
      'id' => $xpath->evaluate('string(key[@type="your_id"])', $item)
    ]
  );
  foreach ($xpath->evaluate('review', $item) as $review) {
    var_dump(
      [
        'nick' => $xpath->evaluate('string(author_nick)', $review),
        'email' => $xpath->evaluate('string(author_email)', $review)
      ]
    );
  }
}
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(18) "CYBEX-525A/DA-IPOD"
}
array(2) {
  ["nick"]=>
  string(5) "Brock"
  ["email"]=>
  string(12) "bb@GMAIL.COM"
}
```

The second argument or `DOMXpath::evaluate()` is a context for the expression. So it is easy to iterate a list of nodes and fetch data for them.

Xpath functions like `string()` case the first node of a list into a scalar value. If the list was empty, and empty value of the type will be returned.

SimpleXML allows you fetch arrays of nodes using `SimpleXMLElement::xpath()`. Here is no direct way to fetch scalar values, but the implemented magic methods allow a compact syntax.

You will have to cast the returned SimpleXMLElement objects into strings.

```
$items = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString);

foreach ($items->xpath('item') as $item) {
  var_dump(
    [
      'id' => (string)$item->xpath('key[@type="your_id"]')[0]
    ]
  );
  foreach ($item->xpath('review') as $review) {
    var_dump(
      [
        'nick' => (string)$review->author_nick,
        'email' => (string)$review->author_email
      ]
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you won't use DOMDocument, you can try :

```
foreach($languages->item as $item){               //loop through item(s)
    foreach($item->key as $key) {                     //loop through key(s)
        if ($key["type"] == "your_id") echo $key;     //echo CYBEX-525A/DA-IPOD
    }

    print_r($item->review);                         //prints review data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use as example

```html
$xml="".$rs_rssfeed['rss_url']."";
  $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
  $xmlDoc->load($xml);
  
  $xpath = new DOMXPath($xmlDoc);
  
  $count = $xpath->evaluate('count(//item)');

  if($count>0)
  {
   
   
   $x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('item');
   for ($i=0; $i<$count =     $xpath->evaluate('count(//item)'); $i++)
     {
   
      $item_title=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue;
      $item_link=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue;
      $item_desc=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue;
      $item_pubdate=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
}
```

Comment: And for <review> ...</review>  data how to get them ?

Comment: by this way : $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument(); $xmlDoc->load($xml); Please change as per your needs

Comment: again I need this to declare within for loop ? please review my code in post there are more than one review in my file

Comment: please adjust or change as per your choice or meaningful way.  Items and all other will be coming